# Spring boot Scheduler with specified dates

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, quartz-scheduler, spring-scheduled

I have a requirement to read data from rest API for each and every minute and save that data it into DB. I am facing some issue  to implement the rest URL for the start date and end dates. As of now from the current date I am able to execute it, but when I specify the start date and end date then for every one minute in between the start date and end date  I need to make a call to rest API.

Note : I am using @Scheduler annotation for this one.
Rest API URL is formed dynamically like below :

```
private Optional<String> buidURL() {
        TimeZone timeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone(Constants.TIME_ZONE);
        Date d=DateUtils.addDays(new Date(), -1);
        java.text.SimpleDateFormat format = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat(Constants.DATE_FORMAT);
        format.setTimeZone(timeZone);
        String jpQueryReqParam =appProperties.getRest().getReqParam();
        String jpQuery = appProperties.getRest().getUri();
        Optional<String> feed = null;
        try {
            feed = Optional.of(jpQuery + URLEncoder.encode(jpQueryReqParam.replace("$queryTimestamp", format.format(d)), StandardCharsets.UTF_8.toString()));
            
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.info("Error occured at buidURL() " + e);
        }
        return feed;
    };
```

and then calling rest API :

```
Optional<String> uri = buidURLFromTo();
String url=uri.get();

ResponseEntity<String> feedResponse = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET, getRequest(headers()), String.class);
```